# Get natural clojure conj order

Tags: collections, clojure

`(conj coll x)`, for performance reasons, will add `x` to the end of some collections and to the beginning of other collections.

Is there a way to check whether the collection will be naturally add-at-end or add-at-beginning? I.e.

```
(conj-at-end? x) ; false for lists and true for vectors.
```

It is fairly easy to write my own, by checking if something is a vector or list, etc, but this is error prone in case there is a new collection added or something changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conj` is a part of [`IPersistentCollection` interface](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IPersistentCollection.java). This interface defines only three methods:

- [conj](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj) - adds new element;
- [empty](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/empty) - returns an empty collection of the same type;
- [equiv](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/=) - performs equality checks.

So, there is nothing like `conj-at-end?`.

I don't think it could be implemented, either. For example, how would you define it for internally unsorted collections like [hash-maps](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Maps%20(IPersistentMap)) and [hash-sets](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Sets)?

```
(conj #{1 2 3 4 5} 6)
; => #{1 4 6 3 2 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Does `conj` add to the beginning or the end of a collection?*

The question only makes sense for a sequential collection, for which you can just try it:

Define

```
(defn conj-at-end? [coll]
  (and (sequential? coll)
       (= (conj (empty coll) 1 2) [1 2])))
```

Then

```
(conj-at-end? []) ;=> true
(conj-at-end? ()) ;=> false
```

and

```
(conj-at-end? #{}) ;=> false
```

We also need the corresponding

```
(defn conj-at-beginning? [coll]
  (and (sequential? coll)
       (= (conj (empty coll) 1 2) [2 1])))
```

Then

```
(conj-at-beginning? []) ;=> false
(conj-at-beginning? ()) ;=> true
```

and

```
(conj-at-beginning? #{}) ;=> false
```

Note that a set is neither `conj-at-beginning?` nor `conj-at-end?`.

---

This rather pat solution would be upset if, for example, `clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap`s, produced by `array-map`,

- were stable under `conj`, which they are not, and
- elected to comply with the empty `clojure.lang.Sequential` interface,
  tested for by `sequential?`, which they do not.